# Gentoo package mask not working with exact version number

Tags: gentoo, package-management

I installed mysql-5.6.42 on a Gentoo system. There's a newer version 5.7.24, but I don't want to upgrade for that version. So I masked the package under `/etc/portage/package.mask`

```
=dev-db/mysql-5.6.42
```

When I want to upgrade for example php portage wants to upgrade mysql to 5.7.24.

Why does `package.mask` not work?

I tried `<=dev-db/mysql-5.7.0` the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your versions again 
`=dev-db/mysql-5.6.24` vs. `>dev-db/mysql-5.6.42`.

```
echo ">dev-db/mysql-5.6.42" > /etc/portage/package.mask/mysql
```

I think there is a typo in your question. Perhaps it is also in your config.

See also: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Knowledge_Base:Masking_a_package

Comment: Sorry it was a typo in my question.

Comment: @dragi did you try with `>`? Does it solve your issue? If so, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Thanks. It's working with > and the exact version number.